# Opening Files in file path but being able to change the date on new workdays

Tags: vba

I open multiple files at my job and would like to know how to open different files by concatenating a workday variable into the file path. Is this possible?

Code:

```
Sub File_Demo()

Dim pathname
Dim Date_X
Dim Date_Y


Date_X = “02.01.22”
Date_Y = 20220201

Pathname = 
“C:\Users\Jinx\Desktop\PDF_Files\2022\Feb\& Date_X &\PDF_FileName & Date_Y &.pdf”

ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink pathname

End Sub
```

I would use this code to open multiple files at once by using a workday - 1, -2, -3, etc type of variable but am stuck on where to start in this process.

Answer (score 0):

The `Date` Keyword can be used in VBA to get the current date value. The [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) function can then turn the date value into whatever format you supply. On that article I linked above, they give a useful chart of [how to create a date format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications#date-symbols).

`Format(Date, "mm.dd.yy")` would be "02.18.22" today and "02.19.22" tomorrow.

`Format(Date, "yymmdd")` would be "220218" today and "220219" tomorrow.

If you need pieces of the current date, like the Year or the Month you can use the aptly named `Year` and `Month` functions. `Year(Date)` would return 2022. And `Month(Date)` would return 2. If you need the month as a three-letter abbreviation, `Format(Date, "mmm")` would give you "Feb".

So for your file path you can do:

```vb
Pathname = "C:\Users\Jinx\Desktop\PDF_Files\" & Year(Date) & "\" & Format(Date, "mmm") & "\" & Format(Date, "mm.dd.yy") & "\PDF_FileName" & Format(Date, "yymmdd") & ".pdf"
```

If you need to change the date, and re-build the pathname, simply replace `Date` with a different value. You can even have a loop like

```vb
'From yesterday to three days from now
For myDate = Date - 1 to Date + 3
    Pathname = "C:\Users\Jinx\Desktop\PDF_Files\" & Year(myDate) & "\" & Format(myDate, "mmm") & "\" & Format(myDate, "mm.dd.yy") & "\PDF_FileName" & Format(myDate, "yymmdd") & ".pdf"
    'Do Stuff
Next
```

Notes: I also noticed that the quotation marks in your post were not standard " marks. That will cause an error in VBA since they will register as unrecognized symbols. Additionally, strings must be concatenated with `&` symbols, but those must be **outside** the quotation marks.

Eg. myString = "abc" & "def"

NOT myString = "abc&" "def"

Comment: I don't know if there is meant to be a space after "PDF_FileName". I did not include a space in this answer, you may want to adjust it to better match your file naming format.